# How do make ajax function for multiple divs on the page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I've coded a commentbox and i successfully made a function that delete the comment in ajax without refreshing the page. The problem is, the ajax function wont delete other comments untill i refresh the page. How can i fix this? im new to ajax. Thank you. And sorry for my english im swedish.

// Eymen

A better explanation:

This is the PHP code that echo out my comment:

```
while($evtMsg = $event->fetch_assoc())
    {   

    echo'

        <div id="activity" class="comment'.$evtMsg['id'].'">
        <div class="settings"><hr><hr><hr></div>
        <div class="actSwine"></div>
        <div class="act" id="delete">&times;<div class="abtSwine"></div><div class="abtbtn" id="deletewid">Radera</div></div>
        <div class="act" id="favo" onclick="alert(\'hello world\');">Favorisera<br><div class="abtSwine"></div><div class="abtbtn" id="favowid">Inl&auml;gget kommer att hamna under "Mina favoriter"</div></div>
        <div class="act" id="raport" onclick="alert(\'hello world\');">Anm&auml;l<br><div class="abtSwine"></div><div class="abtbtn" id="raportwid">Det h&auml;r inl&auml;gget &auml;r kr&auml;nkande.</div></div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
        <div class="activitylabel">
        <img src="'.$this->getUserId($evtMsg['userid'], "Profilepic").'" />
        <div class="activityname"><?php echo "@".$username." , " . $fname . " " . $lname ?></div>
        <div class="activitydomain"><?php echo $domain; ?></div>

        <div id="clear"></div>
        <p>
        '.$evtMsg['message'].'
        </p>
        </div>

        </div>  

        ';

        $id=$evtMsg['id'];

    }
```

Everything is fine here. Comments are working, and everything is printed on the page.

Now here comes the ajax code that removes my div.

var id = $("#activity").attr("class");

```
$("#delete").click(function(){



    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "deletestatues.php",
        cache: false,
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(msg)
        {


            $("."+id).fadeOut('4000');

        }

    });
```

Comment: We can't see what your code does, so we won't be able to answer this until you provide the actual code you have a problem with.

Comment: it depends a lot on how are you trying to do this. Care to show us some code? If your code works only once it might be due to inconsistent or duplicate div ids to almost any other possible reason.

Comment: There's the code of the Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, and from your explanation I get that you are giving the same id for more than one element in the page. When JavaScript, and jQuery looks for an element in the page by ID, it looks only for one element with the mentioned ID and returns the first element it finds with the ID you have specified. That's why your ajax call doesn't remove more than one.
If you can give your comment a class name rather than id, and change your selector to a class selector, it should remove all the comments.

Comment: So, did i get it right. When JS looks for an element by ID it only checks for one specifc. But if its given a class it can stay active and look for more?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. ID for an element in a page should be unique. You cannot give the same ID to more than one element.

Comment: Thank you. But how do i solve this. Is there a way to insert the unique id beside the class ? like for example class="style1 10". I've seen something like that on facebooks divs for example. Or should i use the whole class attr. for the id.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple class name on each element. So when you are generating your element, add id to the class too, don't forget to put space between class names. Also I don't think you can only add numbers as class name, so you add a letter a two before the id, for example comment10, and then in jquery look for `$('div').hasClass('comment' + id).fadeOut('4000')`, something like that.

Comment: It still gives me the same result. I switched selectors, from id to class. It still only removes 1 comment. And the rest i need to refresh the page in order to remove the other one.

Comment: could you please put code for your HTML/PHP, only the section you are creating the comment, I will try to create the same problem and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Check the code, i did an edit to show you both PHP, html and Ajax.

Comment: Change `$("."+id).fadeOut('4000');` to `$(".comment"+id).fadeOut('4000');`